# How can i make the size of the div standard whilst changing the elements inside it to accommodate the div?

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I want to make the div a standard size of 330px. But when I do it, the elements in the div will get screwed up.

```
<div class="col-md-3 m-wthree" style="height:330px;">
                                <div class="col-m">
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.id" class="offer-img">
                                        <img src="@item.productImage" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width:auto;height:124px;">
                                        <div class="offer"><p><span>Offer</span></p></div>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="mid-1">
                                        <div class="women">
                                            <h6><a href="single.html">@item.productName</a></h6>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mid-2">
                                            <p><label>$@item.productOriginalPrice</label><em class="item_price">$@item.productCurrentPrice</em></p>
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="add">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger my-cart-btn my-cart-b " data-id="@item.id" data-name="@item.productName" data-summary="@item.productName" data-price="@item.productCurrentPrice" data-quantity="1" data-image="@item.productImage">Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGLtA.png)
[With % as height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeoJg.png)

```
.m-wthree {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.add{
    text-align:center;
}

.mid-2 p{
    float:left;
    font-size:0.9em;
    color:#B4B4B4;
}
.mid-2 p em{
    font-style:normal;
}
.mid-2 p label{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-weight:400;
    margin-right:6px;
}
.mid-2 {
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

Above is the CSS code for the custom CSS. The CSS all seem ok and does not look like it is affecting anything....

Comment: Did you try using % instead of px for elements size? Also, post your code so we can see exactly what is going on.

Comment: It doesnt work tho... i'll post the image if i use %

Comment: Are you using custom written CSS styles? I see there is a class named "add". Please 
 also post your CSS styles used here.

Comment: the problem is that the children inside the div has more height than the container div. try reducing image height, this should fix the problem. Also it would be better if you provide css code

Comment: the problem is not with the image but with the spacing in between the product name and the price. How do I make it such that it will change to accommodate the height of the div?